# MVC view: Data validation using RegularExpression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 questions regarding MVC view  validation using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations:

1. How do I verify if a value entered in a text box is a URI?
2. How can I verify using RegularExpression if the URL entered in a Box does not start with HTTP:// or ends with ".m3u8"

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
[RegularExpression(@"((((ht)tp?:\/\/)?[^\/\s]+\.(m3u8))(\/\S*)?)", ErrorMessage="Not a Valid URL")]
public string URL { get; set; }
```